# best way to compare two pose estimates from different sources

Tags: navigation, nav-msgs, robot-localization, base-odometry, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a mobile robot with `navigation_stack` up and running. The robot is able to navigate properly from point A to point B. I am using encoders to get the odometry data and IMU, encoders and Lidar ([AMCL](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl)) using [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) to localize the robot and [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) for planning. Now, I have a Ultrawide band sensor which gives the pose of the robot in the global frame. I want to compare the pose estimated by UWB sensor and the actual pose of the robot (output of `robot_localization`)(both gives pose_estimate in the map frame). Both poses are of the form of `nav_msgs/Odometry`. I know I can subscribe to both topics and compare the pose values from both of them and see how different they are. I was just wondering if there is a standard way or a better way to compare two pose estimates of the same type coming from different sources. Any suggestions regarding it will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220727/best-way-to-compare-two-pose-estimates-from-different-sources/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-11-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-11-12**:
The values are going to be time stamped from both, correct? I usually use MATLAB for something like this. You can eyeball it with `rviz`, but MATLAB is great for this kind of thing.

**Comment by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on 2016-03-08**:
I want to know this answer too... can you update? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Python is a great alternative for this as well. You can read directly from bag files and use any number of plotting tools to visualize the data you desire.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1